# Understanding QML_INTERFACE

Tags: qt, interface, qml, qt6

I've a really hard time understanding what the [QML_INTERFACE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_INTERFACE) and [QML_IMPLEMENTS_INTERFACES](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_IMPLEMENTS_INTERFACES) macros are supposed to do. Naively I assumed that the macro does what it says it does, registering a non-instantiable ("uncreatable") type to the QML type system. A type I can then use as a custom property to bind to a specific implementation.

Let's get concrete (no pun intended) and elaborate with a simple example, an interface with a single QString property:

```cpp
class QmlInterface : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QML_INTERFACE
  Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ get WRITE set NOTIFY changed)

public:
  virtual ~QmlInterface();
  virtual QString get() const = 0;
  virtual void set(QString const& name) = 0;

signals:
  void changed();
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QmlInterface, "QmlInterface")
```

And a class which implements that interface (declarations omitted for simplicity):

```cpp
class QmlImplA : public QmlInterface {
  Q_OBJECT
  QML_ELEMENT
  QML_IMPLEMENTS_INTERFACES(QmlInterface)

public:
  QString get() const final;
  void set(QString const& name) final;

private:
  QString name_;
};
```

An instance of this implementation is then created in C+ and an interface pointer gets passed to the QML engine right before loading the .qml file

```cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
// url to .qml file
std::unique_ptr<QmlInterface> qml_impl_a{std::make_unique<QmlImplA>()};
engine.setInitialProperties({{"qml_impl_a", QVariant::fromValue(qml_impl_a.get())}});
engine.load(// url);
```

I then assumed I could just import the interface in my .qml file and use it with the underlying implementation like this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QmlInterface

ApplicationWindow {
    required property QmlInterface qml_impl_a
    // ... 
}
```

However this doesn't work. QML complains that `QmlInterface is not a type`

Upon googling for some QML_INTERFACE examples I found a passage in [Cross-Platform Development with Qt 6 and Modern C++](https://www.packtpub.com/product/cross-platform-development-with-qt-6-and-modern-c/9781800204584) which says that:

> QML_INTERFACE registers an existing Qt interface type. The type is not instantiable from QML, and you cannot declare QML properties with it.

Wait... what? Is this true? The official documentation doesn't mention this anywhere. As this would practically render interfaces completely useless I assume the book is wrong here?

For now I got my example working by making the interface a normal [QML_ELEMENT](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_ELEMENT) and adding [QML_UNCREATABLE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_UNCREATABLE) to prevent instantiation from inside QML. This works and does what I intended in the first place. I still wonder though did I do something wrong or are the macros supposed to do something else entirely and are just named badly?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get it just as you I thought I'll be able to use
the interface as if it had properties in qml.
But it seems like qml Interfaces exists merley to pass upcast to them in properties.
[See the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_INTERFACE)

> When you assign a QObject sub-class to this property, the QML engine does the interface cast to FooInterface* automatically.

Here is an Example:

---

*interface.h*

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QObject>

class FooInterface {
    QML_INTERFACE
        public:
                 virtual int data() = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(FooInterface, "MyApp")


class MyImplementor: public QObject, public FooInterface{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    Q_PROPERTY(int data READ data CONSTANT);
    Q_PROPERTY(FooInterface *interface READ as_interface CONSTANT)
    QML_IMPLEMENTS_INTERFACES(FooInterface)
public:
    MyImplementor(){};
    int data() override{
        return 2;
    }

    FooInterface* as_interface(){
        return this;
    }
};
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "interface.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.loadFromModule("interface_poc", "Main");

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.qml*

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import interface_poc

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Text{
        text: `reper for interface: ${implementor.interface}`
    }
    MyImplementor{id: implementor

    }

}
```

This is what you get:
[image: poc]